# Page with discussion board does not refresh after creating a new discussion within a modal dialog

Tags: 2013, javascript, modal-dialog, discussion-board

I'm using the following code to allow users to create a new discussion topic in a modal dialog, rather than on a new page:

```
// When called, this function opens the dialog.
function openDialog(pUrl) { 
var options = {
    url : pUrl };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

// When called, this function opens the new or existing discussion in a modal dialog instead of on a new page.
function clickMe() {
    $('a[href*="NewForm.aspx"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'openDialog("' +  $(this).attr('href') + '")');
        $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
    });
    $('a[href*="Forum.aspx"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'openDialog("' +  $(this).attr('href') + '")');
        $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
    });
}

window.onload = function () {
    // Timeout in case the script doesn't load properly. 
    clickMe();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        clickMe();
    }, 500);
};
```

This works fine. When I click on "New discussion" it opens in a modal dialog and I can fill in a topic and a message, but when I click "OK" in the dialog the page does not automatically refreshes. If I manually refresh the page, I can see my new discussion. But I want it to refresh automatically whenever a new item is added.

How can I achieve this? Is there a setting for this or should I solve this with JavaScript (and if so, how?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `dialogReturnValueCallback:RefreshOnDialogClose` to your options object:

```
var options = {
    url : pUrl,
    dialogReturnValueCallback:RefreshOnDialogClose
};
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)